# .NET Core - Properly stopping Kestrel

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

Community,
I want to gentle stop Kestrel and a running .Net Core app to make it completes existing queries, prevent it from handle new queries and when all existing queries are done - stop the app and Kestrel.

I need it to setup CI/CD in Kubernetes, where I have balancer routes to Kestrel without nginx, to achieve zero downtime while deployment new app version.

Perfectly would be nice to have something similar to `nginx -s quit

Can anyone suggest the solution or share knowledge how to organize zero downtime with dotnetcore in Kubernetes?

I tried to Google the solutions - didn't worked out for me. Killing the process are not the option.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you provide any code samples what you have tried so far and pinpoint the part where you are having trouble or missing a logic?

Comment: Where is kestrel running? In your pods?

Comment: Yes, Kestrel in pods

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You could use nginx as revrese proxy server. It is a suggested strategy for .NET Core hosting. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1

[image: nginx as reverse proxy]

**Solution 2:**

**Isn't correct. Leaving it here for others to not go this route. Read @David's comment below.**

You'll have to try this yourself. and it's very risky. You might lock yourself out.

.UseKestrel(options => { options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 0; })

If you can configure `KestrelServerLimits` `MaxConcurrentConnections` to 0 you should be able to stop all the traffic.
I don't know how you can configure these limits at runtime. But it'll be fun to see an implementation of this.

Comment: That second option isn't right. Kestrel already handles graceful shutdown based on the signals sent to it (sigterm e.g.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @davidfowl. I'll highlight it in the answer. It was a solution from quick read and I used very skeptical language, showing my limited understanding. Thanks for pointing out.